# Flexbox not working - it seems to only apply to some of the child elements?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So in my code I have a press page with container set to flexbox. the img grid container has 23 card containers in them with images etc. All the cards aligned properly before (within img grid container) however, now only a part of the child elements have flexbox inherited but about 9 of the last items haven't. Posting some pictures. Here is my code. I know this is a lot of code in the HTML but a lot of it just repetition of containers, I'm new :( - have attached a screenshot, I want all the images to be in a row like the thin ones at the left. Thanks.
[image]

```css
.img-grid {
  width: 70vw;
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 2rem;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.press-info {
  width: 350px;
  height: 460px;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  perspective: 1000;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.press-info:hover .card {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.face.front img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.face.back {
  background-image: var(--gradient);
  background-size: 400%;
  background-position: right;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2rem;
  color: black;
  transition: background-position ease-out 0.8s;
}

.face.back:focus {
  background-position: left;
}

.face.back a {
  transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.face.back a span {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="press-container">
  <div class="img-grid">
    <div class="press-info">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="front face">
          <img src="press/press-1.png">
        </div>
        <div class="back face">
          <a href="https://oddamagazine.com/project/fashions-future-designers/">ODDA MAGAZINE : FASHION'S
                        FUTURE
                        DESIGNERS <span>⬈</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="press-info">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="front face">
          <img src="press/press-2.png">
        </div>
        <div class="back face">
          <a href="#">HASHTAG LEGEND : MAY 2020</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="press-info">
      <div class="card">

        <div class="front face">
          <img src="press/press-3.png">
        </div>
        <div class="back face">
          <a href="https://www.kaltblut-magazine.com/to-the-ones-that-hurt-the-most/">KALTBLUT Magazine : To
                        the
                        ones that hurt the most <span>⬈</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="press-info">
      <div class="card">

        <div class="front face">
          <img src="press/press-23.png">
        </div>
        <div class="back face">
          <a href="https://1granary.com/designers-3/graduate-shows/csm-ma-fashion-show-2020-full-line-up/">ONE
                        granary: CENTRAL SAINT MARTINS
                        MA FASHION SHOW
                        2020 : FULL LINE-UP <span>⬈</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="press-info">
      <div class="card">

        <div class="front face">
          <img src="press/press-4.png">
        </div>
        <div class="back face">
          <a href="https://wwd.com/fashion-news/fashion-scoops/central-saint-martins-ma-fashion-recycling-craftsmanship-1203487690/">WWD
                        : Central Saint Martins MA Fashion Champions Recycling and Craftsmanship <span>⬈</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="press-info">
      <div class="card">

        <div class="front face">
          <img src="press/press-5.png">
        </div>
        <div class="back face">
          <a href="#">milk magazine hk: october 2019 : FROM BLOOMING YOUTH TO FASHION</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="press-info">
      <div class="card">

        <div class="front face">
          <img src="press/press-6.png">
        </div>
        <div class="back face">
          <a href="https://the-comm.online/blog/into-the-woods/">the comm online : into the woods
                        <span>⬈</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="press-info">
      <div class="card">

        <div class="front face">
          <img src="press/press-7.png">
        </div>
        <div class="back face">
          <a href="https://www.sleek-mag.com/article/wearable-slime//">SLEEK MAGAZINE : Meet the CSM fashion
                        grad
                        making clothes out of slime <span>⬈</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="press-info">
      <div class="card">

        <div class="front face">
          <img src="press/press-8.png">
        </div>
        <div class="back face">
          <a href="https://1granary.com/designers-3/schools/central-saint-martins/one-year-out/">ONE GRANARY
                        : ONE
                        YEAR OUT<span>⬈</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="press-info">

      <div class="card">

        <div class="front face">
          <img src="press/press-9.png">
        </div>
        <div class="back face">
          <a href="https://whynow.co.uk/read/samson-leung-finds-richness-in-linguistic-mistakes-and-mistranslation/">why
                        now digital : Samson leung finds richness in liguistic mistakes and mistranslation
                        <span>⬈</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="press-info">
      <div class="card">

        <div class="front face">
          <img src="press/press-10.png">
        </div>
        <div class="back face">
          <a href="https://www.dearboymag.com/stories/samson-leung">Dear Boy Magazine : Interview with Samson
                        Leung
                        <span>⬈</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="press-info">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="front face">
          <img src="press/press-11.png">
        </div>
        <div class="back face">
          <a href="https://www.dewmagazine.com/under-the-radar-talent-samson-leung/">UNDER-THE-RADAR TALENT :
                        SAMSON
                        LEUNG <span>⬈</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="press-info">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="front face">
          <img src="press/press-12.png">
        </div>
        <div class="back face">
          <a href="http://example.com/introducing-samson-leung/">I'm Young! : Introducing Samson
                        Leung
                        <span>⬈</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="press-info">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="front face">
          <img src="press/press-13.png">
        </div>
        <div class="back face">
          <a href="">Rain Magazine -> Interview: Samson Leung
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>

            <div class="press-info">
               <div class="card">

                  <div class="front face">
                     <img src="press/press-14.png">
                  </div>
                  <div class="back face">

                  </div>
               </div>

            </div>
            <div class="press-info">
               <div class="card">

                  <div class="front face">
                     <img src="press/press-15.png">
                  </div>
                  <div class="back face">

                  </div>
               </div>

            </div>
            <!-- </div> -->
            <!-- <div class="press-column -4"> -->
            <div class="press-info">
               <div class="card">

                  <div class="front face">
                     <img src="press/press-16.png">
                  </div>
                  <div class="back face">

                  </div>
               </div>

            </div>
            <div class="press-info">
               <div class="card">

                  <div class="front face">
                     <img src="press/press-17.png">
                  </div>
                  <div class="back face">

                  </div>
               </div>

            </div>
            <div class="press-info">
               <div class="card">

                  <div class="front face">
                     <img src="press/press-18.png">
                  </div>
                  <div class="back face">

                  </div>
               </div>

            </div>
            <div class="press-info">
               <div class="card">

                  <div class="front face">
                     <img src="press/press-19.png">
                  </div>
                  <div class="back face">

                  </div>
               </div>

            </div>

            <div class="press-info">
               <div class="card">

                  <div class="front face">
                     <img src="press/press-20.png">
                  </div>
                  <div class="back face">

                  </div>
               </div>

            </div>
            <div class="press-info">
               <div class="card">

                  <div class="front face">
                     <img src="press/press-21.png">
                  </div>
                  <div class="back face">

                  </div>
               </div>

            </div>
            <div class="press-info">
               <div class="card">
                  <div class="front face">
                     <img src="press/press-22.png">
                  </div>
                  <div class="back face">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Look at the indentation of the code snippet. You are missing at least one closing `a` tag.

Comment: I think @Turnip identified the issue-- if you drop your code in the W3 HTML validator you'll find you have some malformed markup issues-- missing close tags and such.  The browser will generally do its best to try to guess your intentions but it isn't foolproof, and can lead to some bizarre behavior.  I'd recommend installing some sort of linting plug-in in your editor to highlight errors, and fix all of them and see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing one closing `<a>` tag

```
<a href="">Rain Magazine -> Interview: Samson Leung
```